# How to read collection data from Mongodb and publish into kafka topic periodically in spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-kafka

I need to read my mongo DB table data periodically and publish it into a Kafka topic using spring boot. I have created a collection in Mongo DB and inserted a few records in Mongo DB. Further, I want to read the data from Mongo DB periodically and need to publish those table data in Kafka's topic using spring boot. I'm very new to spring batch scheduler. Can you please suggest me an idea to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is more relevant to Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#overview

So, you configure a `MongoDbMessageSource` with a `Poller` to read collection periodically.
And then you have service-activator based on the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` to damp data into a Kafka topic.

See more in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.4.0-M3/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka

Not sure though how to do that with Spring Batch...

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will try it and let you know if I have any doubts